# R evaluate character/string as the calling function name

Tags: r, function, tidyverse, expression-evaluation

I had a use case where I wanted to evaluate command line `args` as function names. For example,

```
r_script.R print --number 2
```

I will take r package `docopt` as an example here. The arguments typically are indexed by its own names, e.g. `args$print` refer to the string value `"print"`. Actual R code would just be,

```
if (args$print){
   if (args$number){
       # call print()
       print(as.numeric(args$number))
   }
}
```

When I have a long list of functions like `print`, I'd write a massive `if-else-loop` to cope with it and it quickly becomes tedious.

Is there a way, for example using `quosure`, `eval`, or methods alike to replace this logic such that I can just write only a few lines of code to get the job done?

For example, the ideal logic would be,

```
func_enquo -> enquo(args$func)  # func is in place of `print`
func_enquo(value)  # what matters is the print argument here.
```

I have tried `enquo` by writing a wrapper function and it didn't work; I tried `eval_tidy` which was just to no avail (code is just not valid.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it, you want to use a first argument as a function name? Then try to use [`get()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html) somehow:

```
do_something <- function(fct, arg) {
   get(fct)(arg)
}

do_something("print", "Hello")
#>[1] "Hello"

do_something("mean", 1:5)
#> 3
```

Note that you have to be careful what you pass into. Then you can refer to argument as args[1], not args$print, if it's always the first one somehow like this:

```
func_enquo -> get(args[1])  # func is in place of `print`
func_enquo(value)           # what matters is the print argument here.
```

Does that help?

Comment: thanks this looks very promising, let me try it out shortly, I'll revert back.

Comment: thanks your solution did work! I had to tweak my code a little bit to get it working but it fits my purpose